# Root or flash Galaxy S 2 with Odin 3.07

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-2, rom-flashing, odin

I need to completely erase my current Android OS from my Galaxy S2 and install a fresh version from scratch.

I have Odin 3.07, the ".tar.md5" file and the Samsung drivers. I already did some "flashing", but my device was not "completely" restored, just updated.

I need a full re-install. What thing to check in Odin to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

**Options:**

- Auto Reboot
- F. Reset Time

**Files [Download]**

- PDA: .tar file

[image]

Source: [AndroidCentral](http://forums.androidcentral.com/sprint-galaxy-s-iii-rooting-roms-hacks/219308-guide-how-flash-tar-files-odin-3-07-a.html)

Comment: I think also would be needed to delete user data from many folders on the filesystem, if the phone was rooted (there can be garbage). Factory reset also should be needed (does that F. Reset Time?) for /data/ folder. I clean the phone by: 1. mount all partitions 2. delete all folders and files but /efs/ folder (please remember always to make a backup copy of this folder/partition!) 3. install new ROM (stock or custom)